# Different distances of same route when used as opposite points, Google map

Tags: javascript, php, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using distance matrix api to calculate distance between two points.
I want when same point Source = A and Destination = B, When used in opposite Like Source = B and Destination = A, It should give me same distance even reversing the parameters. Like here in below link . I have used both of them in opposite source and destination but the distance is coming different.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Kingshill+Avenue%2C+Northolt+UB5+6NY%2C+United+Kingdom&destinations=Newmarket+Road+Cambridge+CB5+8RX

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Newmarket+Road+Cambridge+CB5+8RX&destinations=Kingshill+Avenue%2C+Northolt+UB5+6NY%2C+United+Kingdom

Any way of getting same distance, I checked the documentation and was unable to find out the way.

Thanks

Comment: This is kind of a weird question because the distance is based on the real world, where the best route from A to B might not necessarily be the same as the best route from B to A. Just think of a one-way street connecting A to B. The distance is the same, but not by car. How to "fix" this depends on how you use the information, and why you want it to not match reality.

Comment: @ChrisG Actually when it goes to customer's mind, He will be conscious about it that why the distance is not same as he is going to follow the same path. This would really have an impact on the price accordingly which is the main point.

Comment: Well, one quick and dirty fix is to simply sort origin and destination alphabetically, that way B->A will also return the A->B distance.